# Pig: Multiple calls to external method

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to use methods `REPLACE`, `SUBSTRING` and `INDEXOF` in my Pig, but I am unable to use it in a nice way.

- First case: `REPLACE` in `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`:

  ```
  data_split = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, 
      MY_REGULAR_EXPRESSION)) 
  AS (
      timestamp: chararray,
      url: chararray,
      REPLACE(url , '.*?://', '') AS clean_url: chararray);
  ```

I would like to use REPLACE to remove the leading `http://` in URL. In this case I am getting:

```
Error during parsing. Encountered " "(" "( ""
```

- Second case: Reusing output:

  ```
  ws = FOREACH data_split {
      clean_url = REPLACE(url , '.*?://', '');
      url_index = INDEXOF(clean_url, '/');
      web_server = SUBSTRING(clean_url, 0, url_index);
      GENERATE
          web_server,
          timestamp,
          ip
          ;
  ```

Neither this case works, when I try to reuse `clean_url` from previous call to `REPLACE`, I am getting

```
Attempt to give operator of type 
    org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc       
    multiple outputs.  This operator does not support multiple outputs.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use a `UDF` within the `AS clause` in which the schema is specified.
I assume you already have it in this way:

```
inp = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (line:chararray);
data_split = FOREACH inp 
               GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, MY_REGULAR_EXPRESSION)) 
               AS (url:chararray, timestamp:chararray);

res = FOREACH data_split GENERATE REPLACE(url , '.*?://', ''), timestamp;
...
```

As for your second question:
 Which Pig version do use use? I think this was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2134), in version 0.10.0 I couldn't reproduce it.